# Link for absolute positioned image offset

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my site, http://www.jamesarmenta.com/ , there are a group of images that are set to `position: relative;` and randomly positioned around the screen via JQuery. Each image is coded like so:

```
<a href="/wallpapers">
    <img src="/images/wallpapers.jpg" class="project" alt="Wallpapers">
</a>
```

For some reason this link is clickable in the top left of the screen, even though the image is positioned elsewhere.

It **only happens with this link (wallpapers),** which happens to be the first image in the HTML. Any idea why this is? Thanks!

Relevant code:

```
<div id="projectWrapper">

  <a href="/wallpapers">
    <img src="/images/wallpapers.jpg" class="project" alt="Wallpapers">
  </a>

  <a href="/selectedposters">
    <img src="/images/selectedposters.png" class="project" alt="Selected Posters">
  </a>

  <a href="/mylefthand">
    <img src="/images/mylefthand.png" class="project" alt="My Left Hand">
  </a>

  <a href="/logos">
    <img src="/images/logos.png" class="project" alt="Logos">
  </a>

  <a href="/colornames">
    <img src="/images/colornames.gif" class="project" alt="Color Names">
  </a>
```

Link to JQuery code:

https://github.com/jamesarmenta/jamesarmenta.github.io/blob/master/_site/js/home.js

Comment: Remove `position: relative` of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the inspector I see that the image in the first link is `position:relative`, which gives the link some width and height, making it clickable. All the other links contain images which are `position:absolute`, so these images do not affect the dimensions of their parent links, which are all 0px x 0px and therefore unclickable

Comment: This is it! Good eye - I didn't see that the first image is indeed `position: relative`. Not sure how/why it is being assigned this way, but changing manually in Chrome dev tools solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I inspect your page, I can see that the images are correctly placed but the link tags are in their original position.

So the first guess is that your moving the image and not their containers, the links.

In your JS when your doing  `$('.project').each(function() {...});` but you should get the links (the parents of the image).

If you get the links instead, you could, for each of them, position them where you want, access to their child's, the images, and do your work on them.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to add some css. Add "pointer-events: none;" to  #projectWrapper and add "pointer-events: auto;" to all its nested  elements.

Answer (score 1):

If the images have `position: relative`, it means that they are relativley moved away from their original position in the document flow by the distances specified in the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` parameters. But their original space is still kept free in the document flow, and that's where the `<a>` tags are, which function as containers in this case.

The solution would be to give the relative position not to the images, but to the `a` tags, or to *their* containers.

Addition: Or use absolute positioning on the links, which will not reserve any space anymore in the document flow, but, still anchor the absolutely positioned elements to their parent elements (and their position), but only if the parents are also positioned relative or absolute.